# how I animated and restart animation by clicking same button in gsap

Tags: gsap

I want to add gsap animation on my website, But I want to get the animation by clicking a button and then also restart the using the same button, how could I do it using gsap

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
const animation = gsap.to("div", { x: 600, paused: true });

const button = document.querySelector("button");

button.addEventListener("click", () => animation.restart());
```

```css
div{width: 100px; height: 100px; background: teal; border-radius: 5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.10.4/gsap.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<button>Button</button>
```